# Getting Permission Denied error on manager loadFromPreferencesWithCompletionHandler

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, vpn

In my app I am trying to configure VPN settings in App load delegate. I am calling following method in my app delegate

```
- (void)configureVPN {
    NEVPNManager *manager = [NEVPNManager sharedManager];
    [manager loadFromPreferencesWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable loadError) {
        if (loadError) {
            NSLog(@"vpn setup error: %@", loadError);
        } else {
            [manager setOnDemandEnabled: YES];

            NSMutableArray *rules = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            NEOnDemandRuleConnect *connectRule = [NEOnDemandRuleConnect new];
            [rules addObject:connectRule];
            [manager setOnDemandRules:rules];

            [manager saveToPreferencesWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable saveError) {
                if (saveError) {
                    NSLog(@"vpn setup error: %@", saveError);
                } else {
                    NSLog(@"vpn config set");
                    NSError *connError;
                    [manager.connection startVPNTunnelAndReturnError:&connError];

                    if (connError) {
                        NSLog(@"Unable to connect to VPN: %@", connError);
                    } else {
                        NSLog(@"VPN connection established");
                    }
                }
            }];
        }
    }];
}
```

but I am getting error on `manager loadFromPreferencesWithCompletionHandler`

Error:
`Failed to load the configuration: Error Domain=NEVPNErrorDomain Code=5 "permission denied" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=permission denied}`

I thought it was because of missing capabilities but `Personal VPN` is enabled in capabilities.

Comment: is your problem solved ?

Answer (score 16):

Go to **Xcode -> Project -> Targets -> Capabilities** and
Enable VPN and Enable Network Extensions.
[image]

Comment: how to do that in xcode 13?

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue, go to Xcode > Project > capabilities and enable personal VPN.

Answer (score 0):

1. In my case, I had `added the Capabilities correctly`, but an error is still reported
2. when I `restart my iPhone` , then run the project, every thing work fine